# Invoke a batch file

Tags: c#

I am trying to execute a batch file with the given code below

```
private void buttonDisable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process si = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            si.StartInfo.FileName = "Q:\\disable.bat";
            si.Start();          
        }
```

But it just comes up with this error :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception'
> occurred in System.dll
>
> Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified

The file does exist in the location

Comment: does  q:\\ is network drive

Comment: Do you have permission to access that directory?

Comment: Q Drive is a local drive not a network drive. And I do have permission to access the directory

Comment: Add a `if (!File.Exists("q:\\disable.bat")) { MessageBox.Show... }` just above your code.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions for that file? Maybe a security does not let you access this file.

Comment: ok thankyou - the file does not exist according to the if statement, but it is there on the drive

Comment: @ultrapulse I already told you that!!  ;-)

Comment: Is that code executing inside of an ASP.NET application? If so, those apps do not have access to driver letters.

Answer (score 0):

The likely explanation for this problem is that the user context that executes the code does not have the Q drive mapped. So, in other words, you can see the file, but the executing code cannot. Perhaps this is running under ASP.net, for instance.

The other plausible explanation is simply that the file does not exist.

Comment: Im executing this on my local machine where the q drive in installed on

Comment: It seems that in the context of the executing code that file does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

that's normal because .bat is not a process

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", @"/c Q:\disable.bat")
```

could you  please  try this link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90143/Mapping-Network-Drive-using-C

if you can force the drive mapping I think  you will be able  to access  the drive

Comment: No. The default value for `UseShellExecute` is `true` and so the shell association for .bat does the rest. And even then, with `UseShellExecute` as `false`, `Start()` manages to run it fine

Comment: ok  but you agree that 'UseShellExecute' was not set

Comment: It defaults to `true`. But it works either way. Try it out to see.

Comment: ok that's true ok what do you  thing  if he force  the mapping  of his drive